# Python common cx_Oracle connection in multiple files

Tags: python, sql, global-variables, database-connection, cx-oracle

Please guide me, I think there some gap which I am not able to get.
I have used cx_oracle to connect to my oracle database and extract data. Now I need to call this connection string in multiple different scripts. However I am not able to establish the connection in the other files. I did search on this topic and found post that suggested to have a common file, so I created a **conn_var.py** that contains the connection string. This file looks like below -

```
import cx_Oracle
import pandas as pd

report_id = 8412
country = 'es'
period = '2023'
data_schema = 'SUPPORT'

type = 'sup1'

if type == 'sup1':
   conn1 = cx_Oracle.connect('abc','xyz','//....')
elif type == 'sup2':
   conn1 = cx_Oracle.connect('pqr','klm','//....')
elif type == 'sup3':
   conn1 = cx_Oracle.connect('lmn','hij','//....')
```

now I include this file in my first file and it works fine and I am to extract. **file1.py**

```
import cx_Oracle
import pandas as pd
import file2
from conn_var import *

extract1 = pd.read_sql("select * from SUPPORT.report_d",con=conn1)
```

But when I follow the same in file2, it gives me an error. Note that I am calling file2 in file1

**file2.py** looks like below -

```
import cx_Oracle
import pandas as pd

from conn_var import *

extract2 = pd.read_sql("select * from SUPPORT.report_f",con=conn1)
```

Please help!! where am I going wrong. why does it not work for file2? Also in file2 I do not get the variables that I declared in **conn_var.py** like **report_id,country,period etc**. How can I declare them globally so that they are available in all files.

Comment: What is the error?  Are you trying to connect to multiple databases in the same process?  Also consider [upgrading cx_Oracle](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a).

Comment: I am getting connection error. Let me try upgrading cx_Oracle

Comment: I still getting the connection error even after update

Comment: _What is the error message_?

Comment: The error is DatabaseError: DPI-1010: not connected

Comment: That means your connect call didn't run.  Do some debugging and see what is and isn't being called.